# Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my Spring-boot app on Kubenetes.
App is running perfectly when using this command > `mvn spring-boot:run` on 'Cloud Shell'
But when I run on docker using following command:

```
docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 \gcr.io/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/synebiz:v1
```

It gives following error:

```
[2018-12-11 13:59:39.771:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@50b494a6{ROOT,/,file:///jetty/webapps/ROOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{/ROOT}
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<init>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:91)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
```

my pom.xml as follows:

[myexamples/pom.xml](https://github.com/ChkBuk/myexamples/blob/master/pom.xml)

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.